# Почему вылетает исключение при копирование файла (filesystem C++)

Tags: c++, файловая-система

Мне нужно создать функцию, принимающую директорию. С этой директории, все файлы формата txt переместить в папку test.

Снизу виден код, вылетает ошибка.

```
vector<string> files = getAllFiles(dir); 
    for (auto f : files) {
        if (f.substr(f.find_last_of(".") + 1) == "txt") {
            filesystem::path from(f), to("D:\\books\\test");
            filesystem::rename(from, to);
        }
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В векторе хранится ссылки на файл. Получил я их таким способом -

```
vector<string> getAllFiles(string dir)
{
    vector<string> files;

    for (auto i = filesystem::directory_iterator(dir); i != filesystem::directory_iterator(); i++)
    {
        if (!is_directory(i->path()))
        {
            files.push_back(i->path().string());
        }
        else
            continue;
    }

    return files;
}
```

Comment: Вам нужно извлечь из исходного пути имя файла и склеить с путем к целевой директории.

Comment: Да, это помогло. Спасибо !

Comment: `rename(from, to / from.filename())` как то так

Comment: Поправте меня, если я не прав, но, по-моему, rename - это перемещение файла, а не копирование